# How to debug vscode with specific language configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying debugging a localized version of vscode built by myself. When I click `Launch VS Code` or use `scripts\code --remote-debugging-port=9222`, a instance of built vscode will be launched. However, its locale is `en` and even if I run `configure language` and change the `locale` to other values, it's still `en` after restarted.

Could someone point me to the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a full build by running gulp `vscode-[platform]` in the source directory.This will create a `VSCode-[platform]` directory within this directory start vscode.In case of windows, it is `Code-OSS.exe`.